# MomentJS returns wrong unix timestamp

Tags: javascript, time, momentjs, unix-timestamp

In moment, I have time (object):

```
Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: false, _pf: {…}, _locale: Locale, _d: Sat Sep 22 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Středoevropský letní čas), …}
```

it is **Sep 22 2018**.

When I call `rangeStart.unix()` on my object, I am getting `1537567200` and it is Sep 21 2018. Why? Where is a problem?

Comment: Which timezone are you in? A UNIX timestamp is always in UTC - you need to apply the timezone to that, if you want to display the current date for your location. Or any timezone to show the date there.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a time zone issue. Moment is considering the time zone and probably changing the date.

timestamp 1537567200 means:

- In your local time zone: Saturday 22nd September 2018 03:30:00 AM
- UTC: Friday 21st September 2018 10:00:00 PM

Try the following and it should work correctly.

```
moment.utc().format();
```